# Getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Trying to send mail through PHPMailer

Error message:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ummasite\MailHandler.php:54 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ummasite\MailHandler.php on line 54

Code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail -> isSMTP(true);
$mail -> isHTML(true);
$mail -> Host  = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail -> Port = '587';
//Set the encryption mechanism to use - STARTTLS or SMTPS
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail account you created credentials earlier
$mail-> Username = 'voiceovers4u@gmail.com';
$mail -> Subject = 'UMMA Database Change';
//Password to use for SMTP authentication - the 16 character password generated you copied before (no brakes)
$mail -> Password = "usonvaejwrzjwmem";
$mail -> Sender = "voiceovers4u@gmail.com";
$mail -> To = "voiceovers4u@gmail.com";
$mail -> AddAddress('voiceovers4u@gmail.com', 'PappaBear');
$mail -> Subject ="UMMA Correspondence";
$mail -> Context = "Sending content using PHPMail function";
$mail -> From = "voiceovers4u@gmail.com";
$Country = $_GET['Country'];
$UFName = $_GET['FName'];
$ULName = $_GET['LName'];
$UGuestID = $_GET['Email'];
$Phone = $_GET['Phone'];
$Org = $_GET['Org'];
$USubject = $_GET['subject'];
$UMessage = $_GET['message'];

$mail -> Body  = "

<h1>Message from UMMA Website</h1>

<p>$UFName $ULName</p>
<p>$UGuestID</p>
<p>$Phone</p>
<p>$Org</p>
<p>$USubject</p>
<p>$UMessage</p>
php if($UReply!=1) ?>
<p>Reply Unnecessary</p>;
php else 
<p>Please reply</p>;
php endif ?>
';
$mail -> AltBody = strip_tags(Body);
$mail -> send();
$str1 = 'Successful!';
$str2 = 'Unsuccessful!';
phpif($emailStatus) {
echo $str1 .;
} else {
echo $str2 .;
}";

?>
```

What can I do to stop this Fatal Error.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: `echo $str1 .;` is invalid syntax, this code couldn't possibly be running as written.

Comment: Your syntax is all over the place. You never close the string you open with `$mail -> Body  = "` before trying to set `$mail->AltBody` (which most likely is where and why you're getting that error). You also can't have `if`-statements (or open/close PHP blocks) inside of strings. I recommend that you [read the basics about strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Ermm... is that your actual password that you just posted?

Comment: `strip_tags(Body);` should be `strip_tags($mail->Body)`

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: Why do you have `php endif ?>` inside the email body?

Comment: The reason for the error is because you start the email body with double quotes, but try to end it with single quotes. So `$mail -> AltBody = strip_tags(Body);` is being expanded as part of the message body, and it can't substitute `$mail` there.